# How to randomize row names of a matrix

Tags: r

I have a gene-expression matrix with 100 cells and 2000 genes for each cell. I would like to randomize the column that contains the gene names (currently they are ordered alphabetically).

I have been trying to use the `sample` function but I can only manage to randomize columns of a cell and not the column with gene names. Any ideas what I'm missing?

(I am working in R.)

Comment: It would help to have a little more info. Are your data actually in a data frame and not a "matrix"? Or are you using output from a particular gene-expression analysis package (i.e. one that has its own unique data type)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as 
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example. Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/) 
for people to work with - if you do so the question would probably be a better site for Stack Overflow than here, but can always be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change *only* the labels without moving the rest of the data, try `row.names (data) <- sample (row.names (data))`.

If you want to move entire rows into a random order, try `data <- data[sample(row.names (data)), ]`.

Comment: This looks like it would totally screw up the names without changing the data at all.  It wouldn't change anything in the "column with gene names."

Comment: I assumed that's what was desired. I'll add a note to that effect.